# How do I separate same numbers from one column in different different columns?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

Suppose I have data like

```
1
1
1
1
2
2
3
3
3
3
4
5
6
6
.
.
.
```

i want this to be separated as

```
1
 1
  1
   1
2
 2
3
 3
  3
   3
4
5
6
 6
```

Comment: Try Text to Columns. Check [this tutorial](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/text-to-columns.html)

Comment: I don't understand - you want to do nothing with your data?

Comment: it will help us to understand if you attach screenshot. and also please post what you tried so far to achieve this.

Comment: Ok, now that you edited your question. Text To Column won't work. You tagged this as VBA. Post the code you have tried

Comment: Actually I want to separate these numbers according to how many duplicates are there

Comment: I was trying this with "Find" function,means if same no. found then cut & paste it to the offset,but as of I'm new in this field I'm not getting the expected answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Sub SplitToColumns()
Dim numbers As Variant, lastRow As Long, i As Long, col As Long
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
col = 1
'read all column A (I assumed you store these numbers there)
numbers = Range("A1:A" & lastRow).Value2
'clear column A, as we will write here
Range("A1:A" & lastRow).Clear

Cells(1, 1).Value = numbers(1, 1)
For i = 2 To lastRow
    'if the value is the same as previous one, we will write in next column
    If numbers(i, 1) = numbers(i - 1, 1) Then
        col = col + 1
    'if number is different from previous, then write in first column (A)
    Else
        col = 1
    End If
    Cells(i, col).Value = numbers(i, 1)
Next
End Sub
```

This generates following output:

```
A    will become     A | B | C
1                    1 |   |
1                      | 1 |
1                      |   | 1
2                    2 |   |
2                      | 2 |
3                    3 |   |
```

Comment: Thank you @Michał Turczyn ,this code is also working too fine.. :)

Comment: I tried the code on the list 1
1
1
1
2
2
2
1
4
5
6
6
Code works but is output that what the TO wants

Comment: @Storax Example input doesn't include such situation. Also, in this case, just sort the column...

Comment: Yes, you are right, the input dos not inlcude this and one could sort beforehand.

Comment: @AkshayJadhav If the answer solved your problem then you should accept it and optionally upvote.

Comment: @Michal Turczyn Sorry for that ,but actually i can't upvote as my reputation is not more than 13 ,for that in need at least 15 reputation points.

Answer (score 4):

If you have data in *Sheet1* like:

[image]

Select the data and run this macro:

```
Sub DataSpreader()
    Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, K As Long, j As Long
    Dim r As Range

    Set s1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set s2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    s2.Cells(1, 1) = s1.Cells(1, 1)
    K = 1

    For i = 2 To Intersect(Selection, s1.UsedRange).Count
            If s1.Cells(i, 1) = s1.Cells(i - 1, 1) Then
                s2.Cells(i, K + 1) = s1.Cells(i, 1)
                K = K + 1
            Else
                K = 1
                s2.Cells(i, 1) = s1.Cells(i, 1)
            End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

will produce this on *Sheet2*:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is another possible solution, if you consider that the input should be coming from one cell and returning to the next single cell:

[image]

```
Public Sub TestMe()
        
    Dim sourceRange As Range
    Dim resultArray As Variant
    
    Set sourceRange = Worksheets(1).Range("A1")
    resultArray = CharacterArray(sourceRange.Value2)
           
    Dim cnt         As Long
    Dim result      As String
    Dim spaces      As String
    
    
    For cnt = (LBound(resultArray) + 1) To UBound(resultArray)
        If resultArray(cnt) = resultArray(cnt - 1) Then
            spaces = spaces & " "
            result = result & spaces & resultArray(cnt) & vbCrLf
        Else
            spaces = vbNullString
            result = result & resultArray(cnt) & vbCrLf
        End If
    Next cnt
    
    sourceRange.Offset(0, 1) = result
    
    Debug.Print result

End Sub
```

And CharacterArray:

```
Function CharacterArray(value As String) As Variant
                
        Dim cnt         As Long
        Dim result      As Variant
        Dim someVal     As String
        
        For cnt = 1 To Len(value)
            someVal = Mid(value, cnt, 1)
            If someVal Like WorksheetFunction.Rept("[^a-zA-Z0-9.]", 1) Then
                If IsEmpty(result) Then
                    ReDim result(1)
                Else
                    ReDim Preserve result(UBound(result) + 1)
                End If
                result(UBound(result)) = Mid(value, cnt, 1)
            End If
        Next cnt
        
        CharacterArray = result
        
End Function
```

Actually, the biggest "problem" with this solution is that you have to find a way to split the value in range `A1` to an array. This is done with the following 3 lines, which remove the new lines from the new array:

```
For cnt = 1 To Len(value)
    someVal = Mid(value, cnt, 1)
    If someVal Like WorksheetFunction.Rept("[^a-zA-Z0-9.]", 1) Then
```

Once you have a nice array with the values you need, you simply need to compare the current and the previous value in the loop like this:

`If resultArray(cnt) = resultArray(cnt - 1) Then`

and to increase the `spaces` with 1, if they are the same:

`spaces = spaces & " "`